# ESLint semi rule doesn't enforce on import statements before class declaration in react-native

Tags: react-native, eslint

I am trying to integrate ESLint on our react-native project by defining the very basic rules. I started with defining `semi` rule. Everything seems ok so far except for the .js files which has a class declaration. `semi` rule doesn't throw warning or error if I don't use semi-colon for import statements.

**.eslintrc.json**

```
{
    "plugins":["react", "react-native"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "rules":{
        "jsx-quotes": [
            "error",
            "prefer-double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"]
    }
}
```

Example .js file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Easing, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import { updateLicense } from '../actions'

class SomeContainer extends Component {
  somefunction() {}
}
```

On the other hand, if there is no class declaration (just `import` and `export` statements) it complains about lacking semi-colons.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: try with this rule "semi": [2, "always"]

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari I tried but it didn't work. I also figured out that none of the rules work if there is a class definition in any `.js` file

Comment: I think you should define render method to display something in Text then check because linter is not working on that file cause of syntax error

Comment: and if you are using the vscode so you can install eslint plugin for best practice.

Comment: This config+example works as expected for me in Sublime. You might want to make sure you have the latest versions installed.

Comment: @ZeeshanAnsari yeap I am using vscode and already installed it.

Comment: @DavidHellsing I checked the eslint version which is 5. Also, I have the latest version of vscode as well. It sounds weird that it works on Sublime. I might open an issue on vscode.

Comment: did you add "eslint.alwaysShowStatus": true, in workspace setting

Comment: actually vscode displays errors. but the problem is it doesn't work for .sj files which includes `Components`.

Comment: because there could be syntax error

Comment: solve the syntax error first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem gone after I started to extend configuration from `airbnb` style with `babel-eslint` option. So, I added;

```
"extends": "airbnb",
"parser": "babel-eslint",
```

lines into `.eslintrc` file.