# jest Unexpected token Import when semicolons are appended to import statements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, babel-jest, vue-test-utils

using the `vue-cli v3` and adding unit testing and using jest if you append semicolons to the end of import statements jest throws an error `Unexpected token import` but when there are no semicolons everything works fine

i tried to search about the effects of semicolons to import statements but i got nothing
as far as eslint is concerned i have the vue cli option eslint with error checking only

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend-jest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.6.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.7.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "jest-transform-stub",
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
  }
}
```

Code examples:

```
// this will not work it doesn't matter 
// which import statement has a semicolon
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})

// however this does
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

describe('HelloWorld.vue', () => {
  it('renders props.msg when passed', () => {
    const msg = 'new message'
    const wrapper = shallowMount(HelloWorld, {
      propsData: { msg }
    })
    expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(msg)
  })
})
```

expected: semicolon has no effect
what happens: test breaks when semicolon is applied

how to reproduce:
  1.`vue create projectname`
  2.make sure you have enabled unit testing with jest using vue-cli options
  3.go to `./tests/unit/example.spec.js` and append semicolons to imports

Comment: even after adding semicolons to import statements my test cases are passed. Jest is not giving any errors

Comment: Can you show your package.json & jest.conf.js?

Comment: Are you using esLint semicolon rules or any other esLint?

Comment: i didn't know a linter could break my code o.O can you please tell me how eslint can break my tests if there are semicolon options?

Comment: I just thought it might be 1 possibility of causing problem?But for me even after adding semicolons test cases are passed.

Comment: should i include enviroment information and step through it with a debugger (problem is i dont understand the code that it shows to me when i step through it with a debugger so how about a screenshot?) and perhaps some enviroment information

Comment: could please try these once ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54180565/eslint-semi-rule-doesnt-enforce-on-import-statements-before-class-declaration-i

Comment: If above link doesn't work try this out once please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453894/allow-semi-colons-in-javascript-eslint

Comment: thank you for your time!

Comment: could you please tell me did it work?

Comment: Issue solved? could you tell me What was the solution?

Comment: apologies none of the above worked so i figured to stop wasting my and your time with something that wasn't important, hey if it aint broke dont fix it; dont use semicolons!. thank you for your help but nothing worked and this was not a very important problem for me personally.